When using local self-attention how do keys and queries wind up having compatible dimensions if if different sized convolutions are used to make them?
In the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.02143 on page 3 in figure 1 an architecture is described.

As can be seen in the upper left, the keys for Local self-attention are generated using a 3x3 convolution on the input. The same input is then concatenated with the output of that and further processed.  From my understanding the input is a stream of velocity and acceleration vectors. So a 3xm matrix where the (2n)-th column is the n-th velocity measurement and the (2n+1)-th column the n-th acceleration measurement. I would assume that applying a 3x3 convolution to this creates a 1x(m-2) matrix. How would one concatenate that with a 3xm matrix?
